# is there any way to fetch data from many to many tables using spring without infinite json format?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

**user entity**

```
@Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Integer id;
// ... more properties

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "User_Boards", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "board_id")})
Set < Board > user_board = new HashSet < >();
//getter and setter and constructors
```

**board entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Board  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int  id;
    String name;
    int P_id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "user_board" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<User> users_of_board = new HashSet<>();
//getter and setter and constructors
```

When I try to fetch data using findAll method I get infinite json object.

For example when I fetch users I have set of boards inside it I have set of users and inside it I have set of boards... etc.

How can I fetch user with his boards and boards with its users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonBackReference` in the class where you don't want to get the linked object.

So, if I've not missunderstood, one user has many boards, and a board owns to an user or many, so fetching one user you get an infinite recursion.

So into `Board` class you have to do:

```java
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "user_board" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference //<--- Add this
Set<User> users_of_board = new HashSet<>();
```

And then, the object will not be infinite.

Also you can check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) article.

Comment: you are the best, I used it and it works but if the user repeated in many boards the json will has just his id so I made costum model to build new json based on returned json from database.